# Disable the Maximixe, Close buttons in popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

In my web application(ASP.net), I used a Popup window using JavaScript. It is working perfectly but I need to **Disable/Hide the Minimize, Maximize, Close buttons and the resizeable handlers** too. Is it possible.... If it can be done, let me know how to achieve it.

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
function ApproveClick(url)
 {
   newwin =window.open(url,'PopupWindow','left=50, top=50, height=200, width=500,  
      toolbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=0,status=yes');
   if(window.focus)
   {
       newwin.focus();
   }

}
```

Comment: Nope. You can't. Use a *modal* with no option to close instead.

Comment: This sounds like a really annoying popup! You might want to consider using absolutely positioned divs in your main window to achieve a similar effect instead of popups.

Comment: Sorry @RobJohnstone, I can't get you. Can you please explain me, what you are trying to say....!!!!

Comment: There is a tutorial here: http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/

Comment: Is it a new window you want or will a modal dialog on the same page work for you?

Comment: Why would you want the "close" button to not be able to work?  The user should have the control of their windows, not the site.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use jQuery dialog box or MS Ajax control toolkit Modal Popup..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cross browser solution (supporting at least IE, Firefox and Chrome), and trying to implement it only through parameters of window.open method, this is not possible. You can play around with dialog=yes,minimizable=no,maximizable=no options to see results but I suppose you won't be satisfied.

For example, in Chrome popups will always be resizeable when you are using window.open function.

So if you are looking for full control of your popups, go with something like javascript dialog (jQuery for example).